# want to show and hide div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am completely new to jquery, and don't understand it 100%. What I want is a div containing text or an image, and when you click on it, it will show another div.

HTML:

```
 <div class="mytrigger">click here</div>
 <div class="mycontent">show this when clicking on the above</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
 $( ".mytrigger" ).click(function() {
   $( ".mycontent" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
   });
 });
</script>
```

so, when you click on "mytrigger", it must show "mycontent.

Comment: Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aF76V/5/ , What error are you getting

Comment: You're aware jQuery is a library that must be included, not a language by itself?

Comment: i assume you want "mycontent" to start as hidden?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just not working. And yes, I want it to start as hidden. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave the function inside your toggle-call away:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".mytrigger" ).click(function() {
        $(".mycontent").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/a8Np4/3/

**Edit:** Wrapped in a DOM-Ready-Call

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine [now](http://jsfiddle.net/hkm9T/)

You might need to put your Jquery inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //Your code here
}
```

Also just hide the second div initially adding a `display:none` style to `mycontent` class.